# Do I have to discharge an antecedent that I assume?

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

For example, if I have the premise:

$P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow R)$

Can I assume P to get:

$Q\rightarrow R$

And then assume Q to get R.

For reductio ad absurdum and arrow introduction I know that you have to discharge the assumptions that you use, I was just wondering if this is the case for assuming the antecedent.

Here is an argument that seems to require the assumption of the antecedents.

$E\rightarrow (\sim F \lor \sim (A \lor D)) \therefore E \land F \rightarrow \sim D \lor G$

Comment: The question is unclear to me: what exactly do you mean by "discharge the assumptions"?  Also, it would probably be useful to know what "natural deduction" system you're actually using, as there are many variants that come under this heading.  One major factor that could very well affect the answer: is your system one where proofs are represented as trees, or is it a more Fitch-style system where proofs are serialized into a series of steps (with indentation or some similar structure indicating which assumptions are required in which steps)?

Comment: Discharging is a privilege, but you’re acting like its an obligation. If you have undischarged assumptions, it means that your proof is conditional on these assumptions.

Comment: [To get a complete proof, all assumptions must be eventually discharged](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2012fa/supplemental/lectures/lec15-logic-contd/lec15.html) If my goal is to get a complete proof then discharging is an obligation. But it seems to me that the assumptions that I make in my question are not dischargable.

Comment: I edited my question with a more concrete example.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, you have assumed $P$ and $Q$ in order to obtain $R.$ So you have $P\to (Q\to R), P, Q\vdash R,$ not $P\to (Q\to R)\vdash R.$ You don’t have the privilege of discharging the assumptions and getting the latter, stronger result :). The proof is complete, it is just not one from weaker premises that you want. (I don’t disagree with your framing it as an obligation in this sense.)

Comment: You have to assume $E \land F$ and "unpack" it with $\land$-elim to get $E$ and $F$. Then use $E$ with $\to$-elim to derive, from the premise : $\lnot F ∨ \lnot (A∨D)$.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen  Indeed.  The point is that one cannot derive $R$ from $P\to (Q\to R)$ by making assumptions of $P$, $Q$ and just throw them away to forget about them.   Assumptions must be *kept or discharged* (via valid rules of inference).  They cannot just be discarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, if I have the premise:
>
> $P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow R)$
>
> Can I assume P to get:
>
> $Q\rightarrow R$
>
> And then assume Q to get R.

You may do that, but discharging those assumptions gets you right back to $P\to(Q\to R)$

Suppose however that you assumed $Q$ *then* assumed $P$, to derive $R$. Discharging the assumptions will deduce $Q\to(P\to R)$ is entailed by the premise.

But $R$ is *not* entailed by $P\to(Q\to R)$, alone.

$R$ is entailed by $P\to (Q\to R)$, $P$, and $Q$.

> Here is an argument that seems to require the assumption of the antecedents.
>
> $E\to(\lnot F \lor \lnot (A \lor D)) \therefore E \land F \to \lnot D \lor G$

This is how a *Conditional Proof* works in Natural Deduction.   Here you assume $E\land F$, derive $\lnot D\lor G$, then discharge the assumption via conditional introduction.

$$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l} #1\\\hline #2\end{array}}\fitch{E\to (\neg F\lor\lnot (A\lor D))\quad:\textsf{Premise}}{\fitch{E\land F\quad:\textsf{Assumption}}{F\quad:\textsf{Conjunction Elimination}\\E\quad:\textsf{Conjunction Elimination}\\\lnot  F\lor\lnot(A\land D)\quad:\textsf{Conditional Elimination}\\\quad\vdots\\\lnot F\to \lnot D\quad:\textsf{Conditional Introduction}\\\quad\vdots\\\lnot(A\lor D)\to\lnot D\quad:\textsf{Conditional Introduction}\\\lnot D\quad:\textsf{Disjunction Elimination}\\\lnot D\lor G\quad:\textsf{Disjunction Introduction}}\\(E\land F)\to(\lnot D\lor G)\quad:\textsf{Conditional Introduction}}$$

Answer (score 0):

You could do so, but the proof would be unfinished. You could discharge each premise in turn to get:

$$P\implies [Q \implies R] \implies [P\implies [Q \implies R]]$$

If you introduced all of your premises at once, you could also prove:

$$[P\implies [Q \implies R] \land P \land Q] \implies  R$$